# ASUS TP202NAS (J202NA) touchpad problems in Lubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

xinput shows the touchpad as ELAN1201:00 04F3:3085 Touchpad. 
The touchpad works, but occasionally it stops working (stalls, becomes unresponsive) for between 30 and 60 seconds.  It's very intermittent.  I've been able to surf the web for up to around 15 minutes before it happens, (but it's happened 3 times in the time it took me to write this).  Also, Clicking with 3 or 4 fingers can result in it getting stuck in scroll mode (where it scrolls instead of moving the pointer). Repeating the 3 or 4 finger clicks will usually bring it out of scroll mode. I've tried switching beetween the synaptics driver, and libinput and back.   Any ideas?

(The touchscreen FTSC1000:00 2808:509C works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad stopped working completely and is no longer recognized by any OS. Obviously a hardware problem.  I've restored Windows and am going to return the computer for refund.  (It's only 3 weeks old.)  I suspect the intermittent problems were hardware related.